# Object detection for a single object only

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision

I have been working with object detection. But these methods consist of very deep neural networks and require lots of memory to store the trained models. E.g. I once tried to train a Mask R-CNN model, and the weights take 200 MB.

However, my focus is on detecting a single object only. So, I guess these methods are not suitable. Are there any object detection method that can do this job with a low memory requirement?

Comment: StackOverflow is more about programming question, visit the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Thus, you should go to : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try SSD or faster RCNN they are easily available in Tensorflow object detection API

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

here you can get pre-trained models and config file
you can select your model by taking look on speed and mAP(accuracy) column as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Following mukul's answer, I specifically recommend you check out SSDLite-MobileNetV2.
It's a lite-weight model, which is still enough expressive for good results.
Especially when you're restricting yourself to a single class, as you can see in the example of FaceSSD-MobileNetV2 as in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md#open-images-trained-models) (Note however this is vanilla SSD).
So you can simply Take the [pre-trained model of SSDLite-MobileNetV2](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_05_09.tar.gz) with the corresponding [config file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config), and modify it for a single class.
This means changing `num_classes` to 1, modifying the label_map.pbtxt, and of course - preparing the dataset with the single class you want.

If you want a more robust model, but which has no pre-trained mode, you can use an FPN version.
Checkout this [config file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config), which is with MobileNetV1, and modify it for your needs (e.g. switching to MobileNetV2, switching to use_depthwise, etc).
On one hand, there's no detection pre-trained model, but on the other the detection head is shared over all (relevant) scales, so it's somewhat easier to train.
So simply fine-tune it from the corresponding classification checkpoint from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models).